# Extracted spectrum depends on number of points sampled

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I have a signal `a(t)`, this is how it looks when I plot it:

[image]

I am trying to extract the eigenfrequencies of this signal using FFT in MATLAB. I do it like this

```
Y=fft( a );
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
plot(P1)
```

Now, it turns out that if I use `Y=fft( a )`, I only get frequencies close to 0 when I plot the spectrum. If I use `Y=fft( a(1:3:end) )`, then I get frequencies at 0 *and* nonzero frequencies.

1. Why do these nonzero frequencies not appear when I do the FFT on the full dataset, but only when I sample every 4th point?
2. Is the nonzero frequency *actually* contained in my dataset or is it an artifact?

Comment: What's `L`? Can you either include a plot of your spectrum, or data for `a`, or a way to generate `a`?

Comment: By taking every 4th (actually, it looks like you take every 3rd) point, you are sub-sampling the data. Any signal energy at frequencies above newSampleRate/2 would get aliased down. You do say that the original spectrum shows only energy near zero, but it also looks like you plot only the first L/2 points of the spectrum. I assume that L is supposed to be the entire length of a? But if L is smaller that might explain your problem. To really answer the question, we would need more information from you (like a and L).

Answer (score 1):

If you change the width that your data set spans for the FFT input, you multiply the data with a rectangular window, which convolves the spectrum with a Sinc function.  The results of this spectral convolution will show up for any spectral frequencies that are not **exactly** integer periodic within the FFTs new width.

Comment: Yes, but I think the OP is asking about taking every 4th (or 3rd, or whatever) sample from the original data. So the issue would be from sub-sampling and aliasing, not windowing.